# Magento Ajax toolbar/pagination not loading correctly for root product category

Tags: ajax, pagination, toolbar

I'm currently learning Magento and have a strange issue with the toolbar/pagination Ajax script.

Custom theme used - [BuyShop](http://themeforest.net/item/buyshop-premium-responsive-retina-magento-theme/4287671)

I'd usually leave code examples, however, I can't work out which code to target.

---

Parent category page: **domain.com/products.html**

Subcategory page: **domain.com/products/juico-juicers.html**

When on a subcategory page the ajax toolbar/pagination script works perfectly. For example if you click page 2, **/products/juico-juicers.html?p=2**, it loads perfectly.

When you do the same on the parent category page, **/products.html?p=2**, it loads incorrectly; I think it's a parsing issue.

Any help on this issue would be great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man this is actually funny.
I took a look at the how the ajax works and here it is.

in `js/VS/ajaxtoolbar.js` there is this line that handles the success of the ajax call and replaces the current products with the the ones returned by the ajax call.

```
$$(".category-products").invoke("replace",list.toolbarlistproduct);
```

This should work fine if you have only one element with the class `category-products`. but for that specific category, you also have the class on the body element because magento adds a class to the body depending on the page. For the category pages this class is `category-<?php echo $category->getUrlKey() ?>` and the url key in your case is 'products'. So you end up with `category-products`.

The solution would be to change the class name contains the response. Or replace it with an id.

Comment: haha I now feel stupid. That said, the script seems flawed as naming your parent category 'Products' must be fairly popular

Comment: @SamHolguin.I don't know how popular it is (I never used it), but you are right. They should have taken this into account. Usually when doing such things you should use `id` and not rely on `class` because is dangerous.

Comment: The curious thing is that on subcategory pages, the body class name also contains the category title `category-products-category-name`

Comment: yes, but `category-products` is not the same as `category-products-category-name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside the `js/VS/ajaxtoolbar.js` file, on line 57, you can see that after the ajax request is finished, the script replaces all blocks with class `category-products` with thre resulted HTML.

The resulted HTML is only the product list, meaning that only that part of the page should be changed. But if you look inside the `<body>` tag, you will see that this also has the `category-products` class name, which means that the entire body of the page will be replaced with the product list block.

Solution: remove the `category-products` class from the body tag so that the script won't replace the entire page with the AJAX result